# Running a C# application (Awesomium) on multiple platforms with the Mono Project

Tags: mono, awesomium

Would it be possible to develop just one application (Xamarin Studio) that uses awesomium mono? Compile it for the mono runtime and it works across all operating systems (win, android, linux, mac, ..)?

This would be magical.

Comment: never heard of awesomium before - but most things run on mono - I guess you have to try it yourself (even better if you can grab the sources - usually you can get it working in those cases)

Comment: I don't think the latest source from Awesomium is available. There exists Awesomium mono for mac. But it appears there is no Awesomium mono for windows. Is this possible?

Comment: Normaly there *is* no difference - but maybe they use some specific plattform P-Invoke so give it a try(?)

Comment: I already tried, but it gives an exception: http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/5131/mono-winmacandroid.html#answer-5132

Comment: It is not magical but ugly, as your app looks like an alien everywhere, and that's why Xamarin does not use this approach for cross platform development.